# makeStyles is throwing error when i call it

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

I don't know whats wrong with MUI but yesterday I was working on my project and makeStyles worked now all of a sudden doesn't work anymore. I get error here where I call it:
[image]

I think the import has something to do with it

```
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/material";
```

I looked on the internet it said to switch material with styles and that doesn't exist.
[image]

Please help i don't know what to do i have to finish this project fast

I am expecting the app not to crash and to have my styles applied

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1. Delete `node_modules` folder
2. Delete `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` file
3. run `npm` or `yarn` install
4. restart idle
5. and also make sure that you have imported `makeStyles` correctly:

`import { makeStyles, createStyles } from '@mui/styles';`